How to CRUD remotely hosted WP database without root?
I have a local app, which writes into two tables of a local MySQL. Additionally, I have remotely hosted Wordpress (I have no root on this host), where the database has corresponding wp_ tables.
I suspect usual WP hostings don't allow to directly access MySQL remotely.
What is the working/usual way to sync local non-WP MySQL tables with those of the hosted Wordpress?

are you talking about taking changes locally and pushing them to production or pulling down changes from production to your local? Note that you need to mark an answer as the correct answer so you'll want to ask for the specific correct way to do it, not just for recommendations, this isn't always possible though especially if it's a matter of opinion. You'd be right to assume most web hosts don't expose MySQL to the open web ( this is a good thing for security )

@TomJNowell I need to push data from local non-wp MySQL to remote wp MySQL.

to exchange data between 2 applications, it's better to use api and not make direct changes in databases.

the answer to this is going to depend on your technical skill, the kind of local environment you set up, the host you chose, and the services available. E.g. the answer for you could be a plugin, it could be SQL dumps, SQL over SSH proxy, etc, there is no golden path official canonical method that you should use here
